# A limit of a number-theoretic ratio

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number. We denote a prime and a composite by $p$ and $m $ respectively.

$cs(n) = $the number of composites $m$ such that $m=2p+1$ and $m\le n$.

$ps(n) = $the number of primes $p$ such that $p=2m+1$ and $p\le n$.

Seemingly as $n \to \infty$, $cs(n)/ps(n) \to 0.5$ or any other value near $0.5$.

I hope that its proof or disproof will be given.

Comment: So $cs(n)$ is the number of odd composite numbers $m \leq n$ such that $(m-1)/2$ is prime, and $ps(n)$ is the number of odd prime numbers $p \leq n$ such that $(p-1)/2$ is composite. Is that right? And you've found experimentally that $cs(n)/ps(n) \to 1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $sg(n)$ denote the number of [Sophie Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) up to $(n-1)/2$, in other words the number of primes $p$ such that $2p+1$ is prime and $\le n$.

Then it is easy to see that

- $cs(n) + sg(n) = \pi((n-1)/2)$
- $ps(n) + sg(n) = \pi(n) - 1$

Standard sieve methods (see, for example Theorem 4 in http://jonismathnotes.blogspot.com/2014/10/selbergs-upper-bound-sieve.html) will show that $sg(n) \ll n/(\log n)^2$, while the Prime Number Theorem tells us that $\pi((n-1)/2) \sim n/(2 \log n)$ and $\pi(n) \sim n/\log n$.  So yes, $cs(n)/ps(n) \to \frac12$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: It would be good to include a reference for the Sophie Germain result.

Comment: @user49640 I added a blog post that mentions using Selberg sieve to deduce the upper bound.  I don't know a good reference offhand, but chances are there is a general enough result of this type in any good book on sieve theory.

Comment: @Erick Wong thank you very much for your proof.